# clock/timer refresh times per second *tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

i'm making a clock but Click the time in seconds, for example, if the user clicks 2 hours, the timer will be like this:

`2:00:00`
`1:59:59`
but When it is refreshed, it replaces the previous label

that's mean:
`2:00:00`
refresh*
`1:59:59`
And the next feature is that if the user hits the minute

Start with minutes and give an error if it exceeds 60 minutes

And the same feature can be done per second

for example:
*`entry = 70 minutes`

`>> erorr! number > 60`*

Can anyone help? my codes:

```
mili_second_app = 60000
def jik():
    a = int(text.get())
    app.after(a * mili_second_app,show)
def show():
    Label(app,text="time is over").pack()
def jik_1():
    a = int(text.get())
    mili_second_app = 1000
    app.after(a * mili_second_app,show)
mili_second_app
app = Tk()
app.minsize(300,300)
app.maxsize(300,300)
text = Entry(app,font=20)
text.pack()
Button(app,text="محاسبه",command=jik).pack()
menu = Menu()
menu_select = Menu(menu,tearoff=0)
menu.add_cascade(label="تغییر زمان",menu=menu_select)
menu_select.add_command(label="برای ثانیه",command=jik_1)
app.config(menu=menu)
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a `Label` in the global scope and assign a `tk.StringVar()` variable to your label's `textvariable` and use that to update the label periodically instead of creating a new label at each interval

```
time_var = tk.StringVar(app, '00:00:00')  # variable w/ default value
time = tk.Label(app, textvariable=time_var)  # create a label
time.pack()
```

Then put `time_var.set('<time value as a string>')` in a function to update the label. You can use `after()` to have the update function call itself repeatedly until the time is up.

Comment: tnx a lot! you save me

Comment: The stringvar adds extra overhead that isn't necessary. You can configure the text on the label widget directly.